# .net Web API Json Property attribute not working when serilize using JsonConvert.serilizeObject

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

Json libarary to convert data to json

> this is my main method which return two list one with property list
>   List and another is List

```
  public static Tuple<List<RoomDayBook>, List<string>> DayBookRowData(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, int SupplierId, bool wantSubRoom)
        {
            DataSet dsDayBook = FillDayBookData(StartDate, EndDate, SupplierId);

           ............................ 
           ............................

                lstDayBook.Add(objDayBook);
            }
            return new Tuple<List<RoomDayBook>, List<string>>(lstDayBook, Guests);
        }
```

In this RoomDayBook class in which i use JsonProperty which give jsonproperty name in json serilization in stand of property name

```
public class RoomDayBook
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "RC")]
    public string RoomCode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "RN")]
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "HS")]
    public bool HasSubRoom { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "RD")]
    public List<RoomDetail> RoomDetails { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SRs", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<RoomDayBook> SubRooms { get; set; }
}
```

it's woking perfectly in normal aspx webmethods but not working in web api please help me find me reason behind it

Comment: Are you using WCF at all? If not, please remove the `wcf` tag from this question.

Comment: no i'm not using WCF

Answer (score 0):

I found problem in different version of  Newton.json library different between class library and Web API Project that's it not convert it in proper format